# How to preserve whitespaces in saxparser?

Tags: java, sax

I need to read a pragraph in xml parser but saxparser is removing carrier return and newline.
so how should i preserve these whitespaces.

```
<Res attr ="mobileDevices"><dev><name>Sasdsd</name><url>http://xxxxx/Samsdsdsdsdung-Galaxy-Grand.png</url>
<desc> GALAXY Grand is outfitted with a deluxe large display to meet your needs. Everything from larger font size to immersive viewing, brilliant visuals are 

guaranteed.Enjoy exclusive viewing experience while on the go.
</desc>
</dev>
</Res>
```

Comment: Can you provide an XML sample, as well as some code?

Comment: You won't really need to preserve whitespace in practical use so why worry ? :)

Comment: i am using cdata to send to send a desc about pragraph.i need to preserve paragraph as it is with whitespaces.and iam missing some content due to \r \n behavior.

Comment: Where is the `CData` section ?

Comment: @user774217 `<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>`